# Tree recursion __contains__

Tags: python, recursion, tree

So far, I got:

```
def __contains__(self, item):        

    if self.root == item:
        return True
    else:
        for subtree in self.subtrees:
            return subtree.__contains__(item)
```

In T1 (T2(T4, T5), T3(T6)) tree model, it can only go through T2 and T3 but not the subtrees of T2 and T3.

Comment: You are returning at the first subtree in `self.subtrees`, so you will always miss the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if subtree.__contains__(item):
   return True
```

you only want to short circuit IFF you find a match ... if you dont keep looking